# Targeting only one select in jquery not all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Targeting only one toggle (the next div after select) in jquery not all of them

This works except it shows all of the toggle when I only want it to show just the one underneath it.

Heres the html

```
$( ".toggle" ).hide();
$(function () {
  $(".binary").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "0"){
      $( ".toggle" ).hide();
    } else {
      $( ".toggle" ).show();
    }
    $("#pane").customScrollbar("resize", true);
  });
});
```

Heres the html

```
                    <div class="option checkbox">
                        <label class="field_wrap">
                            <div class="label">1</div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <select class="binary" name="option_1">
                                    <option value="0"></option>
                                    <option value="1"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toggle">
                    toggle 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="option checkbox">
                        <label class="field_wrap">
                            <div class="label">1</div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <select class="binary" name="option_1">
                                    <option value="0"></option>
                                    <option value="1"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toggle">
                    toggle 2
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try to find a relative selector using `$(this)`

Comment: Did you checked any of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method.

```
$(function () {
    $(".binary").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 0){
            $(this).parents("div.checkbox").next('.toggle').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parents("div.checkbox").next('.toggle').show();
        }
        $("#pane").customScrollbar("resize", true);
    });
});
```

Here is a [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kishor_subedi/DMtNa/).

Comment: Never mind ticking the answer that helped you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try :first selector

```
$(function () {
    $(".binary:first").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "0"){
            $(this).next(".toggle").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).next(".toggle").show();
        }
       $("#pane").customScrollbar("resize", true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
$( ".toggle" ).hide();
$(function () {
  $(".binary").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "0"){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().hide();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().show();
    }
    $("#pane").customScrollbar("resize", true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @Ganesh's answer but has greater specificity, which might be important in your scenario.

```
$(".toggle").hide();

$(function () {
    $(".binary").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            console.log($(this).closest('div.option.checkbox').length);
            $(this).closest('div.option.checkbox').next(".toggle").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('div.option.checkbox').next(".toggle").show();
        }
        $("#pane").customScrollbar("resize", true);
    });
});
```